# AppBar disappears between React routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an almost working simple react routing project. I have an `AppBar` and a `Drawer` (using mui). In the drawer are three items which will re-route the application. I have the routing working fine, but the issue I am running into is that the `AppBar`, thus the navigation for the rest of the app once you are on a certain page, is no longer there. I am using `react-router-dom v4.x.x` incase that matters to you.

**index.js**

```
import 'core-js/fn/object/assign';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MainView from './pages/Main';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, IndexRoute} from 'react-router-dom';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import CloudProperties from './components/cloudproperties';
import CloudPropertiesNew from './components/cloudpropertiesnew';
import ServiceDetails from './components/servicedetails';
import ServiceRegistrationSummary from './components/serviceregistrationsummary';

injectTapEventPlugin();

ReactDOM.render((
  <MuiThemeProvider>
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" component={MainView}>
        <IndexRoute component={CloudProperties} />
        <Route path="cloudproperties" component={CloudProperties} />
        <Route path="cloudpropertiesnew" component={CloudPropertiesNew} />
        <Route path="servicedetails" component={ServiceDetails} />
        <Route path="serviceregistrationsummary" component={ServiceRegistrationSummary} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

**main.js (app.js)**

```
require('normalize.css/normalize.css');
require('styles/App.css');

import React from 'react';
import Header from '../components/Header';



class MainView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    };

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header
          routerProps={this.props.children} />
        <div>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

MainView.defaultProps = {
};

export default MainView;
```

I know it has to do with the children being injected but I thought I was doing that in the `main.js` with `{this.props.children}` (I'm new to react so sorry if obvious).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In React Router V4 you no longer use children like you did in earlier versions of react router.

***Since you presumably want your nav bar visible in all rendered views you just need to remove it from the `<switch>` or `<route>` components entirely***

In your instance, the code would look like:

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <MuiThemeProvider>
    <Router>
      **<NavComponent />**
      <Route exact path="/" component={MainView}>
        <IndexRoute component={CloudProperties} />
        <Route path="cloudproperties" component={CloudProperties} />
        <Route path="cloudpropertiesnew" component={CloudPropertiesNew} />
        <Route path="servicedetails" component={ServiceDetails} />
        <Route path="serviceregistrationsummary" component={ServiceRegistrationSummary} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Here is an example of how I render my app bar with React Router V4:

Render function in my `<App />` component that just gets wrapped by the `<Router>` component.

```
render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <Nav />
      <Snackbar
        open={this.props.snackbar.get().open}
        message={this.props.snackbar.get().message}
        autoHideDuration={4000}
        onRequestClose={() => this.handleSnackbarRequestClose()}
      />
      <TreeViewer />
      <main style={{margin: '0 15px'}}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/'   render={(props) => (<Home {...props} />) } />
          <Route path='/accounts' render={(props) => (<AccountIndex { ...props }/>)}/>
          <Route path='/users'    render={(props) => (<UserIndex {...props }/>)} />
          <Route path='/login'    render={(props) => (<Login {...props}/>)} />
          <Route path='/logout'   render={(props) => (<Logout {...props}/>)} />
        </Switch>
      </main>
    </div>
    );
  }
```

Render function in Nav.js

```
render() {
    const activeStyle = {
      borderBottom: `${colorPalette.accent1Color} 4px solid`,
      paddingBottom: '6px',
      marginBottom: '-12px' 
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <AppBar
          title={<Link to='/' style={{color: colorPalette.accent1Color, textDecoration: 'none'}}><span style={{fontWeight: 200}}>GBDX Dashboard</span></Link>}
          iconElementLeft={ <Link to='/'><img className="logo logo-white" src="/images/dg-logo.svg" alt="DigitalGlobe logo" style={{ height: '36px', marginLeft: '8px' }}/></Link> }
          iconElementRight={ this.state.loggedInUserEmail ? <LoggedInUserInfo userEmail={this.state.loggedInUserEmail} logout={() => history.push('logout', { redirect : location.pathname })} /> : <Login login={() => history.push('login', { redirect : location.pathname })}/> }
        />
    <Toolbar style={{backgroundColor: '#41658b'}}>
          <ToolbarGroup firstChild={true}>
              { this.props.viewer.get() &&
                <NavLink to={`/accounts/${ this.props.viewer.get().account_id }`} activeStyle={ activeStyle } >
                  <FlatButton label="Your Account" style={{color: '#fff'}} />
                </NavLink>
              }
              <NavLink exact to='/accounts' activeStyle={ activeStyle }><FlatButton label="Accounts" style={{color: '#fff'}} /></NavLink>
              <NavLink exact to='/users' activeStyle={ activeStyle }><FlatButton label="Users" style={{color: '#fff'}} /></NavLink>
          </ToolbarGroup>
        </Toolbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Quick preliminary question. So then should I not put the routes in the `index.js` and instead in the `main.js (app.js)`

Comment: @erp actually after looking at your code, the nav bar needs to be at the same level as `<Route>` component just under `<Router>` and just plain JSX component don't have it rendered by the `<Route>` component it at all

Comment: @erp updated with an example of what your code should look like.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try and implement it more like your code first to see if I can get something working. I am like 3 days old @ react so I'm also trying to pick up on best practices.

Comment: Yeah it's a nice little abstraction to just wrap everything in an `<App />` component so that you can end up with something a little more readable when you append the whole application to the DOM, like this:
`ReactDOM.render(
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={theme}>
    <Router history={ history }>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </MuiThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);`

Comment: Where does the `{ history }` variable come from? I thought in v4 that wasn't necessary anymore because it was like bundled or something

Comment: v4 is super into micro-packages so you actually have to `npm i history` separately  @erp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144288/discussion-between-erp-and-maxwell).